# How to store a varible of a function in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have got the following functions in the same class:

```
class example_class(object):

    def function_1(self, list1):
        a = False
        do some stuff...
        print a

    def function_2(self, list2):
        for item in list2:
            self.function_1(item)

var = example_class()
var.function_2([element1, element2, ...])
```

The output I get for example is:

```
element1 True
element2 False
element3 True
...
```

I know that Print doesn't save the results so I would like to store them in a list so later on I can create e.g. a csv file etc.
I'm not sure how I could do this, if someone could help me would be perfect.

Comment: Initialize a list and append the items as you encounter them? It isn't clear what the difficulty is.

Comment: You should really look into utilizing Python 3 since [Python 2 is past the end of life](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: @SunnyPatel Fair point. I phrased it that way because I wondered if there was something involving e.g. scope that I was overlooking. Since they are defining classes, OP is likely at the point of knowing how to put things in lists, so the fact that they didn't try that suggests that there might be more to their problem than I realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function_1 should be returning, not printing, the value of **a**. function_2 can then collect the values in a list, so:

```
class example_class(object):

    def function_1(self, list1):
        a = False
        do some stuff...
        return a

    def function_2(self, list2):
        ans = []
        for item in list2:
            ans.append(self.function_1(item))
```